# OpenCV evaluateFeatureDetector for Python?

Tags: python, opencv, feature-detection, sift

I am working with Python and OpenCV 3.0 and I am trying to evaluate the SIFT descriptor for two images. More specifically I am interested in the repeatability rate. In C++ there is this function that is used to perform the evaluation:

```
 cv::evaluateFeatureDetector(img_1c, img_2c, h12, &key_points_1, &key_points_2, repeatability, corrCounter);
```

However, I have not found any implementation in Python and I do not really understand how (and if) I could use this function. Is there any other way to compute the repeatability rate in python?

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax:

```
 void cv::evaluateFeatureDetector   (   const Mat &     img1,
const Mat &     img2,
const Mat &     H1to2,
std::vector< KeyPoint > *   keypoints1,
std::vector< KeyPoint > *   keypoints2,
float &     repeatability,
int &   correspCount,
const Ptr< FeatureDetector > &  fdetector = Ptr< FeatureDetector >() 
)
```

img1 and img2 are the two images which you want to match, H1to2 is the homography matrix which can be caculated like this:

```
 H1to2 = cv::findHomography( std::vector<cv::Point2f> srcPoints , std::vector<cv::Point2f> refPoints, CV_RANSAC, 1 );
```

The `srcPoints`  and `refPoints` are obtained after performing feature matching.

repeatability and correspCount is the output from the function.

Comment: I do understand how Repeatability Rate criterion works, I was just wondering if there is an equivalent function in Python. Up until now I have tried to write my own code but still I have to test it to see if it produces the same results as "cv::evaluateFeatureDetector" in C++

Comment: You are not answering @GStav 's question.